# How does one install an older version of TypeScript on mac os x?

Tags: macos, compiler-construction, typescript, npm

I am using WebStorm on a mac for development, and the latest stable release only supports 0.8.x version of TypeScript while npm installs 0.9.x, creating various conflicts with IDE.

Currently npm will install 0.9.x version with:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

how can I force it to install older version of TypeScript compiler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
npm install -g typescript@0.8.3
```

should install the latest 0.8 version of TypeScript.